# Display objects attributes in tkinter label

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, label

I would like a label that updates when I push a button. The label is a formated string that prints some attributes of an object.

This is what I tried. It displays properly but won't update.

```
from class_mnoply import *
from tkinter import *

Player1=Player("Hat")
message=str('''
____________________   

{0}
Bank account: ${1}
Dice1: {2}
Dice2: {3}


____________________    
    '''.format(Player1.name, Player1.bank, Player1.dice1, Player1.dice2))



mainWin = Tk()
topFrame=Frame(mainWin)
topFrame.pack(side=TOP)
button1 Button(mainWin,text="ThrowDice",fg="red",command=Player1.rollDice())
button1.pack(side=BOTTOM)
plLabel = Label(mainWin, textvariable=message)
plLabel.pack()
mainWin.mainloop()
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767228/tkinter-button-not-working/5771787#5771787

Answer (score 0):

You have 1 typo in the following statement and 1 potential error:

```
button1 Button(mainWin,text="ThrowDice",fg="red",command=Player1.rollDice())
```

Can you guess what is the typo? If no, you are just missing the `=` sign.

On the other hand, you are assigning the return value of `Player1.rollDice()` to command, but this is not what you want. What you want is just set the `Player1.rollDice` method as the command that is called when `button1` is pressed. Here's the correct syntax (note the absence at the end of `()`):

```
button1 = Button(mainWin,text="ThrowDice",fg="red",command=Player1.rollDice)
```

Then, where is `message` defined in the following statement:

```
plLabel = Label(mainWin, textvariable=message)
```

There's no need to use a `StringVar` object, but if you want, you have first to declare it:

```
message = StringVar()
```

and finally you can use it as `textvariable` for your label.

Assuming you don't know what `lambda` is, this is a working example of what you are trying to do (without using a `StringVar` variable):

```
from tkinter import *


def set_label_text():
    plLabel.config(text='Hello World!')

mainWin = Tk()

topFrame=Frame(mainWin)
topFrame.pack(side=TOP)
button1 =Button(mainWin,text="ThrowDice",fg="red",
                command=set_label_text) # note the absence of ()
button1.pack(side=BOTTOM)
plLabel = Label(mainWin)
plLabel.pack()

mainWin.mainloop()
```

Comment: Maybe I need to be more clear. I get it to display properly, but what i want is for my fomat options for "message" to be updated when i click the button. 
When i call the function rollDice it sets new values to Player.dice1 and Player.dice2. I get the initial values (1) displayed, but when rollDice is called they both still show one.

Comment: Here: `button1 Button(mainWin,text="ThrowDice",fg="red",command=Player1.rollDice())`, remove `()`, because you want not to assign the return value of `Player1.rollDice()` to `command`, but you just want to associate `Player.rollDice` method address to the command, and not actually the returned value of it, as I said before.

Comment: @user274132 See my comment above and my edited answer, if it's what you want